# TCP Socket fails with "endpoint is not connected" in C program

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, benchmarking

I'm having problems getting a socket connection to work.  I'm trying to have a client connect to a server and to send the server some data. If the data is 1 byte, the server will ping pong the byte back. This code is supposed to benchmark a network.

Currently the code dies with the following error:

```
TCP server recv() failed: Transport endpoint is not connected
TCP Sever send failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Why is the connection failing?

This is the code for the server thread.

```
void *tcp_server(void * context){
    printf("TCP Server has started\n");
    struct thread_parameters * read_params = context;
    int block_size = read_params->block_size;
    int thread_id = read_params->thread_id;
    int base_port = read_params->base_port;
    struct sockaddr_in remote_address;
    struct sockaddr_in my_address;
    int recvMsgSize;
    my_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_address.sin_port = htons(base_port + thread_id);
    my_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    int sockid = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int remote_sockid;
    read_params->sockid = sockid;
    char buffer[block_size];
    socklen_t size_remote_address = sizeof(remote_address); 
    if (bind(sockid, (struct sockaddr *) &my_address, sizeof(my_address))<0)
        DieWithError("TCP server Unable to bind socket.\n");
    printf("TCP Server has bound\n");
    if (listen(sockid, 5) < 0) 
        DieWithError("TCP server Listen Failed");
    while(!read_params->work_done){
        if ((remote_sockid=accept(sockid,(struct sockaddr *)&remote_address,&size_remote_address))<0)
            DieWithError("TCP server accept() failed");
        if ((recvMsgSize = recv(sockid, buffer, block_size, 0)) < 0)
            DieWithError("TCP server recv() failed");
        if (block_size == 1){
            if (send(sockid, buffer, recvMsgSize, 0)!= recvMsgSize){
                DieWithError("TCP server send() failed");
            } 
        }
        close(remote_sockid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the client thread.

```
void *tcp_client(void * context){
    printf("TCP Client has started\n");
    struct thread_parameters * read_params = context;
    int block_size = read_params->block_size;
    char *work = read_params->work;
    long work_size = read_params->size_of_subset;
    int thread_id = read_params->thread_id;
    int iterations = read_params->iterations;
    int base_port = read_params->base_port;
    char * server_address = read_params->server_address;
    struct sockaddr_in my_address;
    struct sockaddr_in remote_address;
    my_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    my_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remote_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_address.sin_port = htons(base_port + thread_id);
    remote_address.sin_port = htons(base_port + thread_id);
    int sockid = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int sendMsgSize = block_size;
    char buffer[block_size];
    char * message; 
    socklen_t size_remote_address = sizeof(remote_address); 
    inet_pton(AF_INET, server_address, &(remote_address.sin_addr)); 
    if (bind(sockid, (struct sockaddr *) &my_address, sizeof(my_address))<0){
        DieWithError("TCP Client Unable to bind socket.\n");
    }
    printf("TCP Client TCP Client has bounded\n");
    if (connect(sockid, (struct sockaddr *) &remote_address, size_remote_address) < 0)
        DieWithError("TCP Client connect() failed");
    int j;
    int i;
    int sent_size;
    for (j=0; j<iterations; j++){
        for(i=0;i<work_size; i=i+block_size){
            message = &work[i];
            sent_size = sendMsgSize;
            while (sent_size > 0) { /* zero indicates end of transmission */
                sent_size = send(sockid, message, block_size, 0);
            }
        if(sent_size != 0) DieWithError("TCP Sever send failed");
            if (block_size == 1){
               if (recv(sockid, buffer, sendMsgSize, 0) > 0){
                    DieWithError("TCP Client recv() failed");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    close(sockid);
    printf("iterations: %i\n", j);
    printf("work size: %i\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the server thread. You use the wrong socket descriptor.

From the manpage of **accept(2)**:

> On success, these system calls return a nonnegative integer that is a
>   file descriptor for the accepted socket.  On error, -1 is returned,
>   and errno is set appropriately.

So the return value (`remote_sockid`) should be used for read(2)/write(2) calls:

```
if ((remote_sockid=accept(sockid,(struct sockaddr*)&remote_address,&size_remote_address))<0)
    DieWithError("TCP server accept() failed");

if ((recvMsgSize = recv(remote_sockid, buffer, block_size, 0)) < 0)
    DieWithError("TCP server recv() failed");
if (block_size == 1){
    if (send(remote_sockid, buffer, recvMsgSize, 0)!= recvMsgSize) {
        DieWithError("TCP server send() failed");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I was using the wrong file descriptor for the recv and send then.

Comment: It seems that there is additional problems.  The client now exits with 141 exit code :(  Any idea about that?

Comment: When is the client dieing? (= What is the client's output?)

Comment: The only output i'm getting is:
srun: error: greencompute-2: task 1: Exited with exit code 141

Comment: You should debug where the crash occurs (e.g., by setting a `return 0` statement line by line, to see how far it runs before crashing). But now, I'll probably sleep, so don't expect an answer too early